# How to disable websocket in vite react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

Code:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    hmr: {
      wss: false
    }
  }
})
```

the error itself:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://haron-monitoring.appleseed.kz:24678/' failed: setupWebSocket @client.ts:78
client.ts:106 [vite] server connection lost. polling for restart...

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [
   ...
],
server: {
    port: 3000,
    https: true,
    hmr: {
        host: "yourdomainname.com",
        port: 3001,
        protocol: "wss",
    },
},
```

For more information, refer to this link: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/1926

Comment: how does this **disable** websocket as per the question?